# Kill process buffer without confirmation?

Tags: buffers, process, kill-buffer

I have `C-x C-k` bound to `kill-this-buffer`. But when I enter into a buffer which is running a process like Python or MySQL, if I do `C-x C-k` it asks

> Buffer "*Python*" has a running process; kill it (y or n)?

How can I kill process buffers without confirmation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the corresponding function from the relevant variable :

```el
(setq kill-buffer-query-functions (delq 'process-kill-buffer-query-function kill-buffer-query-functions))
```

**How did I find this ?**

`kill-this-buffer` uses `kill-buffer` internally, which references the variable `kill-buffer-query-functions`.

Comment: I put this line into my startup file and no errors are shown in the message buffer. When I have a scheme process running (started with `run-scheme`) when exiting still a dialog pops up and asks "Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway?".

Comment: @user905686 That's a question asked by `save-buffers-kill-emacs` and unrelated to killing the buffers.

Comment: Now I see that it works for just killing a buffer. I thought exiting emacs would try to kill the buffers and that therefore the confirmation dialog has the same origin. I asked a new question: [Exiting emacs without confirmation to kill running processes](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26565/13091).

Answer (score 8):

Or the simpler one would be :

```
(setq kill-buffer-query-functions nil)
```

Inspired from [abo-abo config](https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs/blob/0a0ce9adc13e19f07a80c9def4435d1e8cf324be/init.el#L68)

Comment: That's making an assumption that `kill-buffer-query-functions` will contain only `process-kill-buffer-query-function`.  This *is* true, by default, in current versions; but that's still not a sensible assumption to make.

Answer (score 3):

This will not affect the global variable scope

```
(let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil))
  (kill-buffer "*Python*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here solve the question but for completness I will show my solution based on [YoungFrog answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14511/24061) which in my opinion leads to a problematic state where no more confirmation will be asked for any process buffer killing.

### Context

I just want to be able to kill `*ansi-term-1*` buffer with no confirmation :

```
(defun perso/close-shell ()

  ;; remove confirmation for process buffers
  (setq kill-buffer-query-functions
    (delq 'process-kill-buffer-query-function kill-buffer-query-functions))

  (kill-buffer "*ansi-term-1*")

  ;; confirmation is now active for other process buffer
  (add-to-list 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'process-kill-buffer-query-function))
```

and revert to the previous state where confirmation is asked for other process buffers.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun custom-kill-buffer-no-confirm (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  "Kill current buffer unconditionally."
  (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
```

Comment: Why do you provide a prefix arg but do nothing with it?

Comment: Remove it if you want.  I vaguely recall getting incompatible argument type errors so that might be why.