# Exiting emacs without confirmation to kill running processes

Tags: process, exit

It turned out not to be the same problem as [Kill process buffer without confirmation?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14509/13091): emacs asks for different kind of confirmations when exiting and when just killing a buffer.

How to specify for all or specific processes (e.g. one launched with `run-scheme`) to be killed without confirmation on exiting emacs?

Comment: A side question is : why isn't that question asked from kill-emacs-query-functions ? I have no idea. Hysterical reasons ? A work around would be to use kill-emacs directly (or write an analogue to sbke which bypasses the question). Another workaround would be  advice sbke with a :before advice that will kill the processes you don't want to be warned about.

Comment: Yet another workaround would be to follow my answer at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14669/sort-of-autoreply-for-specific-messages-in-minibuffer/26357#26357 and code the improvement I suggested in a comment, then use all of that around sbke... ok maybe I should stop now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my own suggestion (second comment on the question), here's an answer which avoids the prompting altogether:

```
(require 'auto-answer)    
(let ((auto-answer '(("\\`Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway\\? \\'" t))))
  (save-buffers-kill-emacs))
```

This uses `auto-answer.el`, available at https://github.com/YoungFrog/auto-answer/blob/master/auto-answer.el (it requires dash.el from your favourite package store, and nadvice.el which is available at least in 24.4).

**Edit:**
If you only want to avoid the prompt for *some* (specific) processes, the documented way to do it is to set its query-on-exit flag to `nil` using `set-process-query-on-exit-flag` when creating the process.

Comment: Thanks, just a few problems: first, please note that it also requires [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/blob/master/dash.el). Then: am I supposed to put it in .emacs? Doing so closes emacs right after startup.
Finally, for selectively disabling asking for *some* processes this approach doesn't seem appropriate, as it only looks for that message (which is common to all processes being killed).

Comment: The dependency on dash is mentionned at the top of that file. The idea behind this code is that you create your own `my-kill-emacs` function and bind that to `C-x C-c` instead of `save-buffers-kill-emacs`. If you want to selectively disable asking for some processes, the obvious answer is to use `set-process-query-on-exit-flag` (set the flag to nil) on those processes when they are created.

Comment: Thank you, this was even more what I was looking for. With `(set-process-query-on-exit-flag (get-process "scheme") nil)` [(doc)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Query-Before-Exit.html) right after `(run-scheme "petite")` the query is disabled directly after starting the process (which in my happens in `.emacs`). Could you add this to your answer? Then I'll accept it .

Answer (score 11):

Emacs 26.1 added the `confirm-kill-processes` variable. To disable confirmation to kill processes on Emacs exit, add to your init file:

```el
(setq confirm-kill-processes nil)
```

Documentation:

> Non-nil if Emacs should confirm killing processes on exit. If this variable is nil, the value of `process-query-on-exit-flag` is ignored.  Otherwise, if there are processes with a non-nil `process-query-on-exit-flag`, Emacs will prompt the user before killing them.