# url-(https)-file-exists-p: ignore interactive behaviour when called programmatically (insecure TLS connection)

Tags: url

I want to use `url-file-exists-p` (or more precisely, the underlying `url-https-file-exists-p`) to detect possible broken links. However, some `https` link makes `url-file-exists-p` require interaction (This even happens when `url-file-exists-p` is called programmatically):

1. when the TLS connection is insecure: a buffer named `*Network Security Manager*` pop up to show certificate information and a prompt is waiting for input as below;
   [image]
   (below is the result of the help).
   [image]
2. ask for user-name and password.

I'm looking for a way to

1. prevent the buffer `*Network Security Manager*` pop up
2. send input to the prompt whenever is needed
3. return different values/symbols depending on the context

   - `t`: secure connection, no prompt showed up
   - `nil`: connection failure
   - TLS: `'always`, `'session` and `'no`: depending on the input (2.) sent whenever a prompt requires one
   - username/password: `'ignored` if username/password are not sent to the prompt causing failure.

Answer (score 0):

I list below several attempts I tried.

1. Associate `display-buffer-no-window` to the buffer `*Network Security Manager*`. This prevent the buffer to pop up, and since `url-file-exists-p` fails to receive input, an error is throw. Finally, intepret the "pop up" as `'no`.

```
(let ((display-buffer-alist
     (cons display-buffer-alist
           (cons "\\*Network Security Manager\\*"
             (cons #'display-buffer-no-window nil))))) 
    (condition-case nil
    (url-file-exists-p url)
      (error 'no)))
```

2. Bound `(minibuffer-message-timeout 0)` in a let-in form.

For whatever reason, the two first attempts fail to deal with the prompt asking for authentification. By inspecting the source code of `url-*` packages, I found a workaround:

> Send a `GET` request instead of a `HEAD` request as `url-http-file-exists-p` do (`url-http-head`).

3. Strangely, the website requiring authentification doesn't require one when is a `GET` request in contrast to `HEAD` request. Obviously, this is just a workaround as a `GET` request may take much more resource than a `HEAD` one.

```
  (defun my/url-http-file-exists-p (url)
    (let ((buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url t t)))
      (when buffer
    (let ((status (url-http-symbol-value-in-buffer 'url-http-response-status
                               buffer
                               500)))
      (prog1
          (and (integerp status)
         (>= status 200) (< status 300))
        (kill-buffer buffer))))))
```

4. Use the [auto-answer](https://github.com/YoungFrog/auto-answer/blob/master/auto-answer.el) package where it is illustrated [in this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26745/23697). To do this, we need to enhance it so that it supports `read-multiple-choice` (the function called when there is an insecure TLS connection).

```
(defun rmc-auto-answer (oldfun &rest args)
  (let ((prompt (car args)))
    (let*
        ((matcher-answer (and (stringp prompt)
                              (--first (string-match (car it) prompt) auto-answer)))
         (dontask (and matcher-answer (cdr matcher-answer))))
      (if dontask
          (--first (eq (car it) dontask) (cadr args))
        (apply oldfun args)))))

(advice-add #'read-multiple-choice :around #'rmc-auto-answer)
```

Finally, by binding the variable `auto-answer`, we can feed the input automatically whenever there is an insecure TLS connection asking for input

```
(let ((auto-answer (list (cons "Continue connecting\\?" ?s))))
             (url-http-file-exists-p url))
```

However, the authentification prompt occurs in an endless loop which means that this attempt is not sufficient (even if we can `auto-answer` username/password).

5. TODO Use [Request.el](https://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/index.html) instead of `url.el`.